# Converting to Mongoid causes error: Could not load database configuration - No such file - [config/database.yml]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, mongodb, postgresql, mongoid

**Disclaimer:** I know there are a couple of questions regarding this issue, but I followed all the answers. posted in those questions and I am still getting the error.

I have a rails app setup using Postgres and am trying to switch to [mongoid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid). Here are the steps I took:

- drop databases
- add `'mongoid', '~> 7.0.5'` and delete `'pg'` gem
- remove all references to `active_record` and `active_storage`
- remove spring gems (known to cause issues)
- update all models to be compatible with `mongodb`
- delete `config/database.yml` and `/db` directory
- switch `devise` and `database-cleaner` to use `mongoid`

After following all of the above steps, I am still getting the error when starting the server:

`Could not load database configuration - No such file - [config/database.yml]`

This doesn't make any sense, because rails should not be loading active record at all, and therefore should not be loading the database config file.

I would really appreciate if someone could be debug this issue.

You can view the [source code of my app under the branch `mongodb`](https://github.com/redline-gh/agilely/commit/849fe5548f6f2c3c5f953e0f055304f2fc743aaa)

**Edit:** I disabled `bootsnap` and `devise` and got the stack trace down to this: (It looks like `active_record is still being loaded`)

```
Puma caught this error: Cannot load database configuration:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:241:in `database_configuration'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:327:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `run'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:28:in `before'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:604:in `catch'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:604:in `block in default_terminator'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block in halting'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:111:in `run!'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:73:in `block in run!'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `tap'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `run!'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
/Users/afamily/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Which branch is devise-free?

Comment: @D.SM I did not commit the devise-free version as it was unsuccessful. However, I created a new rails app skipping active record, and added devise and it was fine, so I don't know if that is the issue

Comment: @D.SM I fixed the issue by copy pasting all my code into a new rails app configured with mongoid. No idea how that worked, git's saying all it did was delete a bunch of comments ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same issue as https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/601, in your case originating from devise here:

```
/home/sandbox/agilely/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:52:in `block in <module:Confirmable>'
```

If you remove devise from your application and you are able to load console successfully, I suggest reporting this issue to devise.

Comment: Following up on this. Remove "action_text/engine" and "action_mailbox/engine" from railties loaded in config/application.rb and you should be good.